# npm install on elastic beanstalk reports no errors but misses dependencies

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a working elastic beanstalk deployment. After adding new dependencies and redeploying, the new dependencies are not installed. Looking through the logs, npm appears to execute successfully with no errors. SSHing into the machine and running `npm install --production` manually also reports no errors, but `npm list` reports missing dependencies. Manually installing each of the packages individually works. However, when elastic beanstalk spins up new instances, the new instances once more are missing the new packages.

What am I missing?

I recently upgraded to Node.js 8 and npm 5, and am using yarn on my local machine, not sure if that is related.

Comment: There's a file named package-lock.json you need to commit this file or you won't have the new dependencies installed.

Comment: How come package-lock.json doesn't get regenerated with updated content based on the new packages from the package.json file? I'm using yarn on the dev side, which doesn't seem to update the package-lock.json file - how are the two supposed to play together?

Answer (score 0):

Npm 5 generates a `package-lock.json` file, while yarn generates its own yarn.lock file. Yarn doesn't update the npm lock file, and npm fails to update it when running `npm install --production`. In effect, using yarn in development appears incompatible with using npm 5 in production. As a work-around, we removed `package-lock.json` from git, letting npm re-generate it.

Comment: You better commit this file